# Angular material data table with server-side pagination “on scroll”

Tags: angular, datatables, pagination, angular-material, server-side

I want to implement pagination on scroll using `angular material data-table`, I found below example on `Angular Material` website but it is not with scroll event pagination.

[Server side pagination without on scroll](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypgqzs)

How can I implement same with scroll? Please guide me.

Comment: let's try it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-data-table-infinite-scroll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Hoàngg it's not working as expected.

Comment: @Hoàngg see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypgqzs